# HTML5/javascript error

Tags: javascript, android, html

If I run the below code as regular html5 code in the browser, Its works fine. I want the same result using android. I am getting the following error:

> 12-08 12:56:26.546: ERROR/Web Console(703): TypeError: Result of
>   expression 'service.useService' [undefined] is not a function. at
>   file:///android_asset/www/index.html:12

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            var iCallID;
            function InitializeService()
            {
                service.useService("http://10.15.1.205/HelloService/Service.asmx?wsdl",  "HelloWorldService");
                service.HelloWorldService.callService("HelloWorld");
            }

            function ShowResult()
            {
               document.write(event.result.value);
            }
        </script>
</head>
    <body  onload="InitializeService()"  id="service" style="behavior:url(webservice.htc)"  onresult="ShowResult()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting your javascript code beneath the body of your html? It looks like your javascript does not know what your element `service` is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I inserted the javascript code inside body tag of HTML but it didn't work.

Comment: what version of android ? what browser ? and browser version ?

Comment: Try inserting it **below** your HTML body, insert your `<script>` tag (with JS code) after `</body>`. Does that help?

Comment: I am using "Device API version 8 (Android 2.2)". I tried running it in IE8, its works fine.

Comment: @user1082868 see my answer below - its an IE specific attribute ... not going work on non IE browsers

Comment: @Tobbe : I tried to put the javascript after the body element inside the HTML tag..... didn't work :(

Comment: I am using "Device API version 8 (Android 2.2)". Default Android browser.

Answer (score 2):

This isnt a problem with HTML5 this is a Internet Explorer only CSS attribute -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530723(v=vs.85).aspx

Cannot find it in any official HTML5 / CSS3 documentation ...

So unless your Android device runs Internet Explorer you need to find an alternative